# I18n::InvalidPluralizationData error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Based on help from this site, I was able to set up a display for the person's age. But when I do something like `<%= distance_of_time_in_words(DateTime.now, p.dob) %>`, I get an `invalidPliralizationData error, "translation data {:one=>"1 an", :many=>"{{count}} ans"} can not be used with :count => 30"`
My yml file has all the translations for datetime:distance_in_words_... where ... defines all the various possible occurrences.

Again help will be highly appreciated. All previous Google searches haven't been fruitful

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think the hash keys are `:one` and `:other` (not `:many`).  I suspect they chose this wording because `:other` also includes the zero case (?).

Anyway, hope that helps!

Answer (score 8):

It seems you didn't define :many in your localization file.

English has only :one and :many

If you are using :en then you should replace :many by :other.

Else if you are using another language you need to check the mapping key for 30 in [config/locales/plurals.rb](https://github.com/svenfuchs/i18n/blob/e4ce5e58f0524ae7c34ca94971363e13aa889f36/test/fixtures/locales/plurals.rb) and define it in your localization file.

For example, 30 should be :many in :ar Arabic

Answer (score 1):

Helped me with such localization file

```
en:
  datetime:
    distance_in_words:
      less_than_x_seconds:
        one:   "1 second" # default was: "less than 1 second"
        many: "%{count} seconds" # default was: "less than %{count}     seconds"
      x_seconds:
        one:   "1 second"
        many: "%{count} seconds"
      less_than_x_minutes:
        one:   "a minute" # default was: "less than a minute"
        many: "less than %{count} minutes" # default was: "less than %    {count} minutes"
      x_minutes:
        one:   "1 minute"
        many: "about %{count} minutes"
      about_x_hours:
        one:   "1 hour" # default was: "about 1 hour"
        many: "about %{count} hours" # default was: "about %{count} hours"
      x_days:
        one:   "1 day"
        many: "%{count} days"
      about_x_months:
        one:   "1 month" # default was: "about 1 month"
        many: "%{count} months" # default was: "about %{count} months"
      x_months:
        one:   "1 month"
        many: "%{count} months"
      about_x_years:
        one:   "1 year" # default was: "about 1 year"
        many: "%{count} years" # default was: "about %{count} years"
      over_x_years:
        one:   "1 year" # default was: "over 1 year"
        many: "%{count} years" # default was: "over %{count} years"
      almost_x_years:
        one:   "1 year" # default was: "almost 1 year"
        many: "%{count} years" # default was: "almost %{count} years"
```

As you can see, :other key changed to :many